# How to dynamically get html of page with PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am writing a wordpress shortcode and I need to get the contents of a specific div on each page that the shortcode is rendered on.

Here is my code so far

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML(//here is where the problem is);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $hidden_listing_id = $xpath->query('//div[id="listing-id-hidden"]');
```

The div is structured like

```
<div id="listing-id-hidden" style="display: none;"> </div>
```

I know I can get the html of a specific url but how would I dynamically get the html of each page that I render the shortcode on.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm don't understand. Are you trying to get the value of div, as if you do an "Ajax" like request from php?

Comment: If yes, you should check the file get contents method

Comment: that would work but I need to dynamically get the url of each page

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Because PHP is not an event language like JS

Comment: i also do not understand what do you mean by dynamically.. is your div id different on each page?

Comment: the url of the page will be different with each page I render the shortcode on